# Can the terms in a 3x3 determinant be any six nonzero numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, constraints

Given six nonzero real numbers $x_1,\ldots x_6$, can you construct a 3x3 matrix such that the six diagonal products that appear in the determinant are $x_1,\ldots,x_6$, respectively?

In other words, can you construct a matrix 
 $\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i\end{bmatrix}$ so that

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
aei &=& x_1\\
bfg &=& x_2\\
cdh &=& x_3\\
afh &=& -x_4\\
bdi &=& -x_5\\
ceg &=& -x_6\\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

If not, is there a neat way to describe constraints on $x_1,\ldots,x_6$ so that this is possible? Or, how many of the six terms can you choose arbitrariily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set of six equations has a solution if and only if following condition is satisfied:
$$x_1 x_2 x_3 + x_4 x_5 x_6 = 0\tag{*1}$$
The "only if" part is obvious because the six equations together imply

$$x_1 x_2 x_3 = abcdefghi = - x_4 x_5 x_6$$

For the "if" part, when $(*1)$ is satisfied, there are infinitely many solutions. Following is one of them.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c\\
d & e & f\\
g & h & i\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \\
-\frac{1}{x_4} & \frac{x_2}{x_4 x_5} & \frac{1}{x_1}\\
x_1 & -x_4 & \frac{x_4 x_5}{x_2}\end{bmatrix}$$

For example, 
$$ceg = \frac{x_1 x_2 x_3}{x_4 x_5} = -\frac{x_4 x_5 x_6}{x_4 x_5} = -x_6$$